# Unable to save the tf.contrib.learn wide and deep model in a tensorflow session and serve it on TensorFlow Serving

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am running the tf.contrib.learn wide and deep model in TensorFlow serving and to export the trained model I am using the piece of code

```
 with tf.Session() as sess:
      init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
      saver = tf.train.Saver()
      m.fit(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(df_train), steps=FLAGS.train_steps)
      print('model successfully fit!!')
      results = m.evaluate(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(df_test), steps=1)
      for key in sorted(results):
        print("%s: %s" % (key, results[key]))
      model_exporter = exporter.Exporter(saver)
      model_exporter.init(
      sess.graph.as_graph_def(),
      init_op=init_op,
      named_graph_signatures={
          'inputs': exporter.generic_signature({'input':df_train}),
          'outputs': exporter.generic_signature({'output':df_train[impressionflag]})})
      model_exporter.export(export_path, tf.constant(FLAGS.export_version), sess)
      print ('Done exporting!')
```

But while using the command `saver = tf.train.Saver()` the error `ValueError: No variable to save is displayed` 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWHLB.png)

How can I save the model, so that a servable is created which is required while loading the exported model in tensorflow standard server? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try sess.run(init_op) first? Does your graph have anything else?

Comment: Yes, I tried using the sess.run(init_op), however I am still facing the same problem.

Comment: Can you print more information [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py#L1016) and compare against what you expect? You may want to try to instantiate the saver later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graphs and sessions are contained in Estimator and not exposed or leaked. Thus by using Estimator.export() we can export the model and create a servable which can be used to run on model_servers.

Answer (score 1):

`Estimator.export()` is now deprecated, so you need to use an `Estimator.export_savedmodel()`.

Here I wrote a simple tutorial [Exporting and Serving a TensorFlow Wide & Deep Model](https://github.com/MtDersvan/tf_playground/blob/master/wide_and_deep_tutorial/wide_and_deep_basic_serving.md).

TL;DR

To export an estimator there are four steps:

1. Define features for export as a list of all features used during estimator initialization.
2. Create a feature config using `create_feature_spec_for_parsing`.
3. Build a `serving_input_fn` suitable for use in serving using `input_fn_utils.build_parsing_serving_input_fn`.
4. Export the model using `export_savedmodel()`.

To run a client script properly you need to do three following steps:

1. Create and place your script somewhere in the /serving/ folder, e.g. /serving/tensorflow_serving/example/
2. Create or modify corresponding BUILD file by adding a `py_binary`.
3. Build and run a model server, e.g. `tensorflow_model_server`.
4. Create, build and run a client that sends a tf.Example to our `tensorflow_model_server` for the inference.

For more details look at the tutorial itself.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Does your graph have any variables then? If not and all the operations work with constants instead, you can specify a flag in the Saver [constructor](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/functions_and_classes/shard5/tf.train.Saver.md#tftrainsaver__init__var_listnone-reshapefalse-shardedfalse-max_to_keep5-keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours100000-namenone-restore_sequentiallyfalse-saver_defnone-buildernone-defer_buildfalse-allow_emptyfalse-write_version2-pad_step_numberfalse-saverinit):
`saver = tf.train.Saver(allow_empty=True)`